# Number divided by 4 by python regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to write code in python's regexes that will pass with strings representing numbers that are divisible by 4. Every number that has last two numbers that are divisable by 4 is divisable by 4
(0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 68, 72, 76, 80, 84, 88, 92, 96):
So I have written some code:

```
import re
r = re.compile('^([048]$)|([-]{0,1}[0-9]*([12]|[16]|[20]|[24]|[28]|[32]|[36]|[40]|[44]|[48]|[52]|[56]|[60]|[64]|[68]|[72]|[76]|[80]|[84]|[88]|[92]|[96])$)')
m = r.search("32") # this is oke
m.group() # this is giving a wanted result
m = r.search("33") # here somthing is not right
m.group() # it shouldn't return 33 but it does
```

Why does my code is not working as I wish to? Why does it accept 33?

Comment: Why are you using a regular expression to test the divisibility of a number?

Comment: It is kind of task that should provide my to enlightment

Comment: [Now you have two problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what `[...]` *does*. They are character classes; if 1 character in that class matches, the text matches:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'[32]', '3')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='3'>
>>> re.search(r'[32]', '2')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='2'>
```

Don't use a character class when you only want to match  literal text.

The following would only match your specific 2-digit patterns:

```
r = re.compile('^([048]$)|(-?[0-9]*(12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)')
```

This works as expected:

```
>>> r = re.compile('^([048]$)|(-?[0-9]*(12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)')
>>> r.search("32")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='32'>
>>> r.search("33")
>>> r.search("33") is None
True
```

You are not matching numbers ending in `00` however (like 100, 200, etc.), which are also divisible by 4.

Note that the expression can be reduced further; the digits 0, 4 and 8 only follow even numbers while the digits 2 and 6 always follow odd numbers:

```
r = re.compile('^-?(?:[048]|[0-9]*(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26]))$')
```

I moved the `-` sign check out to apply to all numbers.

Comment: I have analized your approach. It is logic. Thank you for your time.

Comment: this: r = re.compile('^-?(?:[048]|[0-9]*(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26]))$')
is really helpfull, because my patter has faild on tests. thank you once again

Answer (score 2):

You can significantly reduce the execution paths with this

```
 # ^[+-]?(?:0*[048]|[0-9]*(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26]))$

 ^                   # BOS
 [+-]?               # Optional plus or minus
 (?:
      0* [048]            # just a resultant 0, 4, 8
   |  
      [0-9]*              # any amount of any number
      (?:
           [02468] [048]       # even
        |  [13579] [26]        # or, odd
      )
 )
 $                   # EOS
```