# Python unittest AssertionError - why?

Tags: python

I have a unittest code written by my professor, to check my task. Through cmd.exe I initiate test `python Task303Test.py`, which is containing code like so:

```
"""
NAME: divisable_by_four
PARAMS: string
RETURN: bool
POINTS: 2
"""

import unittest
from Task303 import divisable_by_four

class Task303Test(unittest.TestCase):
    """Testy do zadania 303"""

    def test_simple(self):
        """Prosty test."""
        self.assertTrue(divisable_by_four("32"))
        self.assertFalse(divisable_by_four("33"))
        self.assertFalse(divisable_by_four("-32"))
        self.assertTrue(divisable_by_four("0"))

        for num in range(45000, 47000):
            if num % 4 == 0:
                self.assertTrue(divisable_by_four(str(num)), str(num))
            else:
                self.assertFalse(divisable_by_four(str(num)), str(num))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I have my `divisable_by_four function`:

```
import re

def divisable_by_four(string):
    r = re.compile('^(?<!-)(([048]$)|([0-9]*(12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$))')
    m = r.search(string)
    if m and m.group():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

But I am getting error when testing:

```
self.assertTrue(divisable_by_four(str(num)), str(num))
AssertionError: 45000
```

It is strange for me because I think that I have done everything as I should. Could someone please tell me what is wrong? Maybe the test itself is wrong?

Comment: Are you really doing a mathematical test with a regular expression monster? :-|

Comment: Such a weird way to test your string without casting it to number. Ok, let's do that. Maybe we should add 0|4|8|00|04|08 to regexp? Also, what if string is not number? Or string has spaces? Something like "   124   "? Do we need to test that case too?

Comment: Hint: there are lots of smaller numbers your function fails for (100, 104, 108, etc.)  But looking at your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663065/number-divided-by-4-by-python-regex), Martijn has already explained some of the issues.

Comment: @Ilya Boltnev and DSM, good tip. I have added 00|04|08| to my pattern.
If string is not a number thet it isn't matched, I think. Am I correct?

Comment: Ok, I got it, because that what Martijn written is correct:
r = re.compile('^-?(?:[048]|[0-9]*(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26]))$')

Comment: I am curious, is it a requirement by your professor to write your divisible by 4 checker function using regular expressions instead of the mod operator *%*? Your function as error prone as they come and only pedagogical reasons can justify its implementation.

Comment: This task is required to pass subject that is called automata and formal languages. In normal case I will use % operator.